# Android excel file reading throws exceptions

Tags: android, apache-poi

I am reading xlsx file on android using Apache POI library.which throws very strange error.
My code is given below any help would be more appreciate able.

```
package com.xlsx;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import android.content.Context;

import com.log.UtilityLogCat;

public class ReadXLSXInputDB {

public ReadXLSXInputDB(Context context, String fileName) {
    readXlsx(context, fileName);

}

private void readXlsx(Context context, String fileName) {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(fileName);

        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        UtilityLogCat.LogCatVerbose("XLSX Sheet Name",
                workbook.getSheetName(0));
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("0");
        for (Row row : sheet) {
            for (Cell cell : row) {
                UtilityLogCat.LogCatVerbose("Cell",
                        cell.getStringCellValue());

            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Throws exception.

```
    07-25 21:28:18.348: E/AndroidRuntime(2909): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 21:28:18.348: E/AndroidRuntime(2909): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not         execute method of the activity
07-25 21:28:18.348: E/AndroidRuntime(2909):     at     android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
07-25 21:28:18.348: E/AndroidRuntime(2909):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-25 21:28:18.348: E/AndroidRuntime(2909):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-25 21:28:18.348: E/AndroidRuntime(2909):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-25 21:28:18.348: E/AndroidRuntime(2909):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-25 21:28:18.348: E/AndroidRuntime(2909):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-25 21:28:18.348: E/AndroidRuntime(2909):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-25 21:28:18.348: E/AndroidRuntime(2909):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 21:28:18.348: E/AndroidRuntime(2909):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-25 21:28:18.348: E/AndroidRuntime(2909):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-25 21:28:18.348: E/AndroidRuntime(2909):     at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-25 21:28:18.348: E/AndroidRuntime(2909):     at     dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 21:28:18.348: E/AndroidRuntime(2909): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-25 21:28:18.348: E/AndroidRuntime(2909):     at com.apnfinder.APNSettingActivity.onApnSettingChanged(APNSettingActivity.java:131)
07-25 21:28:18.348: E/AndroidRuntime(2909):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 21:28:18.348: E/AndroidRuntime(2909):     at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-25 21:28:18.348: E/AndroidRuntime(2909):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
07-25 21:28:18.348: E/AndroidRuntime(2909):     ... 11 more
07-25 21:28:18.348: E/AndroidRuntime(2909): Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError:     org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook
07-25 21:28:18.348: E/AndroidRuntime(2909):     at com.xlsx.ReadXLSXInputDB.readXlsx(ReadXLSXInputDB.java:28)
07-25 21:28:18.348: E/AndroidRuntime(2909):     at com.xlsx.ReadXLSXInputDB.<init>(ReadXLSXInputDB.java:20)
07-25 21:28:18.348: E/AndroidRuntime(2909):     ... 15 more
```

Any help would be more appreciatable.

Comment: Did you perhaps do something odd/wrong when converting the POI jars + dependency jars to Android?

Comment: I just downlaod it from http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/poi/release/bin/poi-bin-3.9-20121203.tar.gz and add only pio-3.9.jar and pio-ooxml.jar.
Thats it.
i didn't do any additional step.

Comment: What about the [dependencies of those jars](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components)? (The POI website [lists them quite clearly](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components)!)

Comment: 3 days passed still no helpful reply :)